# UICollectionView width programatically conflicting with storyboard initialization

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, width, viewdidload

I've created a UICollectionView through the storyboard and temporarily positioned it in the view; however, I'd like to overwrite the positions programmatically on launch rather than using the storyboard configuration.

[image]

I thought `viewDidLoad()` was the right location to place make this change?

**Swift 2 Code:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell")
    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white:1, alpha:0.0)

    // Doesn't stretch the width to the device's width on launch. :-(
    collectionView.frame.size = CGSize(width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, height: 200)        
}
```

Comment: are you using autolayout? have you set constraints from storyboard means from interface builder?

Comment: Yes, I have set constraints from the interface builder. Not sure how to reset them other than by going to the UICollectionView's object on the storyboard and clearing the constraints but that doesn't help. It won't change the width programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are setting constraints and then want to change `height` or `width` then you should take outlet of that height or width and increament it's constant value. just ctrl+drag from width constraint to class and make outlate and then increment that outlate's contant property in `viewdidload`.

for example,

```
@IBOutlet weak var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

self.heightConstraint.constant = 200
```

And second thing if you want to keep your collectionview's height equal with device then there is no need to set programatically. autolayout manage it if you set proper constraint. so main point is use autolayout at evrywhere or not at all. dont mix both autolayout and then set frame programatically.

hope this will help :) [image]

Comment: Interesting workaround. I'm trying it right now but I'm not sure what I'm CTRL+dragging exactly from the XIB storyboard. Am I selecting the UICollectionView's object first?

Comment: No you need to select the constraint line which must be of red color in storyboard and then ctrl+drag it to the code

Comment: just select constraint and control + drag from it to class. keep assistant editor open beside with your class. i am uploading image so you will have better idea.

Comment: check the answer now i have uploaded image. :)

Comment: Excellent. I have also found another workaround before I saw your updated answer: insert the line I have under `func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView` instead of `viewDidLoad()`. It seems to do the trick to overwrite the initial configuration from the storyboard. Hope these workarounds help someone out there. Thank you!